# SoapUI load test, calculate cnt in variance strategy

Tags: web-services, soapui, load-testing

I work with SoapUI project and I have one question. In following example I've got 505 requests in 5 seconds with thread count =5. I would like to understand how count has been calculated in this example.

[image]

For example, if I want 1000 request in 1 minute what setting should I set in variance strategy?

Regards, Evgeniy

Comment: seems the example is not posted properly

Comment: @Mehavel, please tell me what information I should provide

Comment: in your question you have mentioned "in the following example" so i was expecting some exmaple... now i understood that you have mentioned it as "for example" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variance strategy as the name implies, it varies the number of threads overtime.Within the specified interval the threads will increase and decrease as per the variance value, thus simulating a realistic real time load on target web-service.

**How variance is calculated** : its not calculated using the mathematical variance formula. its just a multiplication. (if threads = 10 and variance = 0.5 then 10 * 0.5 = 5. The threads will be incremented and decremented by 5)

For example:

```
Threads = 20
variance = 0.8
Strategy = variance
interval = 60
limit = 60 seconds
```

the above will vary the thread by 16 (because 20 * 0.8 = 16), that is the thread count will increase to 36 and decrease to 4 and end with the original 20 within the 60 seconds.

if your requirement is to start with 500 threads and hit 1000 set your variance to 2 and so on.

refrence link:

[chek the third bullet - simulating different type of load - soapUI site](http://www.packtpub.com/web-services-testing-with-soapui/book)

Book for reference:

```
Web Service Testing with SoapUi by Charitha kankanamge
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used the setting you posted: 
Threads = 20
variance = 0.8
Strategy = variance
interval = 10
limit = 10 seconds
I thought it would send about 200 requests on 10 seconds. However I sent 458 requests. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @evgeniy44 in the example i have mentioned 'threads=20''variance=60' for the initial 15 seconds there will be 20 threads hitting the service,so the number of threads will be 20, but its not assured how many times these 20 threads will hit the service within the initial 15 min, and it cannot be controlled. with variance we can set the real time load(load varies from 20 to 36 to 4 and again to 20). but how many times these thread make a request is not controlled.hope this clarifies.let me know if u need some links,for reference i don't have it ready though, but i can find it in my old notes :)

Comment: So, as I understand I can't control frequency of request sending in SoapUI. Very pity.... Anyway, thanks for clarification. I will try to find another tool to work with my load tests.

Comment: hi can i know how to send some 50 requests without a time delay using simple strategy in the soap UI.